# How to crop a triangle

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, 3d, normalization

I am working on some "Face Normalization" Project. 
What I did till now is:

1. Face detection
2. Facial Landmark detection (68)
3. Split the face is a few triangles by connecting the several landmarks (Delaunay Triangulation -->AAM)
4. Create some 3D Model of a generic face (consists of 68 (same as Landmarks) Points) in 3D and also did some Delaunay Triangulation

Now what i need to do now:
I know all the Landmark coordinates and all the 3D coordinates so i want to crop each triangle in 2D and put it on its right place on the 3D generic model to generate a 3D Model of the detected face.

Question: 
1.)Does anyone know a way to crop a single Triangle by knowing all three coords?
2.)And what kind of transformation do i have to use to "copy" the cropped triangle on its right place on the generic 3D model?

I am programming in c++  and took dlib and openCV for the facial landmark detection and on the 3D side I am working with openGL

EDIT:
Maybe it is better to "see" the problem. This is what i have already

[image]

and now i just want to crop all these triangles separately. So how can I crop a triangle (when i know all 3 coords) from a picture and safe it in another window?

Answer (score 0):

In order to crop a triangle, we need to use warpaffine method.

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

/// Global variables
char* source_window = "Source image";
char* warp_window = "Warp";
char* warp_rotate_window = "Warp + Rotate";

/** @function main */
 int main( int argc, char** argv )
 {
   Point2f srcTri[3];
   Point2f dstTri[3];

   Mat rot_mat( 2, 3, CV_32FC1 );
   Mat warp_mat( 2, 3, CV_32FC1 );
   Mat src, warp_dst, warp_rotate_dst;

   /// Load the image
   src = imread( argv[1], 1 );

   /// Set the dst image the same type and size as src
   warp_dst = Mat::zeros( src.rows, src.cols, src.type() );

   /// Set your 3 points to calculate the  Affine Transform
   srcTri[0] = Point2f( 0,0 );
   srcTri[1] = Point2f( src.cols - 1, 0 );
   srcTri[2] = Point2f( 0, src.rows - 1 );

   dstTri[0] = Point2f( src.cols*0.0, src.rows*0.33 );
   dstTri[1] = Point2f( src.cols*0.85, src.rows*0.25 );
   dstTri[2] = Point2f( src.cols*0.15, src.rows*0.7 );

   /// Get the Affine Transform
   warp_mat = getAffineTransform( srcTri, dstTri );

   /// Apply the Affine Transform just found to the src image
   warpAffine( src, warp_dst, warp_mat, warp_dst.size() );

   /** Rotating the image after Warp */

   /// Compute a rotation matrix with respect to the center of the image
   Point center = Point( warp_dst.cols/2, warp_dst.rows/2 );
   double angle = -50.0;
   double scale = 0.6;

   /// Get the rotation matrix with the specifications above
   rot_mat = getRotationMatrix2D( center, angle, scale );

   /// Rotate the warped image
   warpAffine( warp_dst, warp_rotate_dst, rot_mat, warp_dst.size() );

   /// Show what you got
   namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow( source_window, src );

   namedWindow( warp_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow( warp_window, warp_dst );

   namedWindow( warp_rotate_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow( warp_rotate_window, warp_rotate_dst );

   /// Wait until user exits the program
   waitKey(0);

   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help for now, but is it my non understanding of this methode or did you understand my question wrong?